# easy way to bind a listbox to a list<string> in wpf, with safe update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

The question is very simple, yet every time I see similar questions answered here, the answers don't explain a way to do it with a simple example. Here's my code:

xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox_PuntosIntermedios" MaxHeight="80" Height="80" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            </ListBox>
```

And here it is the list of items:

```
List<string> Lista_punto_intermedio = new List<string>();
```

All I did in the load method of the wpf window, was this:

```
Lista_punto_intermedio.Add("testing...");
ListBox_PuntosIntermedios.ItemsSource = Lista_punto_intermedio;
```

It displays the item "testing..." correctly, but when I add a new item in the list, it's not shown in the Listbox. How can I correct my code to show the items without using ListBox_PuntosIntermedios.Items.Refresh(); that sometimes gives me errors that are not even displayed by the debugger.

I've seen other answers, that say "use inotify..." "use mvvm..." but they don't show you an easy way to do it for noobs like myself.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: do quick Stackoverflow google search on the following there are tons of examples out there
`C# stackoverflow bind Listbox with List<string>`

Comment: done that, but the examples are not clear enough for me.

Comment: the examples are so straight forward it's not even funny

Comment: please give me a link with an answer like the one provided by @Steve Wong and I will shut up and agree with you.

Comment: That's not how it works here @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio, do you own research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do in your example is to use an `ObservableCollection<string>` (in the  System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace) instead of a List.  ObservableCollection<> will notify your ListBox when items are added/removed to the collection and your UI will update via the magic of WPF data binding.  This gets you halfway there as your UI will update when the collection changes (new items will appear in the ListBox and removed items will be removed from the ListBox).

```
ObservableCollection<string> Lista_punto_intermedio = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Then, you probably want your ListBox to update when one of the strings change as well (example: if "testing..." was updated to "working...", you probably want your ListBox to display "working...").  For this to work with WPF data binding, you need to implement IPropertyNotifyChanged on the objects in your ObservableCollection.  To do that, you can introduce a new class with a string property for your text.  Maybe something like this:

```
public class MyNotifyableText : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _myText;
   public string MyText {
       get { return this._myText; }
       set
       {
             if(this._myText!= value)
             {
                  this._myText= value;
                  this.NotifyPropertyChanged("MyText");
             }
        }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
             this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
   }
}
```

This object will send notifications to the WPF data bindings when the "MyText" property is changed and this will allow your ListBox to update accordingly. To tie this new object and your ListBox together, you will have to change your XAML so the ListBox displays your "MyText" property and change the `ObservableCollection<string>` to be `ObservableCollection<MyNotifyableText>`

Here's a final code sample:

XAML (note the DisplayMemberPath attribute):

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox_PuntosIntermedios" DisplayMemberPath="MyText" MaxHeight="80" Height="80" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            </ListBox>
```

List of items:

```
ObservableCollection<MyNotifyableText> Lista_punto_intermedio = new ObservableCollection<MyNotifyableText>();
```

Load:

```
Lista_punto_intermedio.Add(new MyNotifyableText(){ MyText="testing..." });
ListBox_PuntosIntermedios.ItemsSource = Lista_punto_intermedio;
```

Lastly, I found this tutorial helpful in learning about WPF data binding: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/

Comment: You couldn't explain it better, and to the point, thanks a lot!!!! You made my day :)

Comment: No problem, Julian.  IMO, WPF has a steep learning curve but totally worth the time/effort/patience needed.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I created a very simple sample solution [here.](https://github.com/orhtun/SimpleListBoxUsageDemonstration)

If you are developing with WPF and also want to use 2-way binding, your best bet is MVVM. There is a learning curve but it is worth it.

In the sample I used MVVMLight toolkit to simplify a few things. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I learned a few tricks from it. Have a nice day.